# Framework Choice / Recommendations for Google App Engine

Tags: java, python, django, spring, google-app-engine

i want to develop a big web application in Google App engine, but I don't know which framework to use in order to obtain the MVC Model. I prefer to use Spring MVC, but I read that several problems with GAE. Another option would be to use django with python but I have never used that. What framework or option do you recommend? Are there other frameworks?

Greetings

Comment: Are there others? Yes, e.g.: http://www.tipfy.org/

Comment: There are no best framework. I would suggest to try a framework in a programming language you are best at. And choose the one that is having extensive documentation and support. And, would really suggest to try a couple of frameworks by creating there quick-start or POC app to see ease of use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which python framework is best for web development in google app engine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70913/which-python-framework-is-best-for-web-development-in-google-app-engine)

Comment: This is way too vague to provide a coherent answer. There are many, many frameworks that work on App Engine, each claims that it's the best. What are your specific requirements that might allow us to select one over another based on something other than personal preference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check out [web2py](http://www.web2py.com) -- it's a full-stack Python MVC framework that's very easy to set up, learn, and use. It was designed to run on Google App Engine out of the box, and there's a [whole section in the online book](http://www.web2py.com/book/default/chapter/11#Google-App-Engine) dedicated to GAE (there are also other references throughout the book discussing a few special considerations when developing for GAE). There's even a "Deploy on Google App Engine" button in the web2py browser-based IDE (see the IDE demo [home page](http://www.web2py.com/demo_admin/default/site) and [GAE deployment interface](http://www.web2py.com/demo_admin/gae/deploy)).

Your web2py GAE apps will also be portable -- you can deploy them on other platforms (e.g., a Linux VPS) without changing your code (though you may want to make some adjustments once you're off GAE and no longer subject to its limitations).

If you have any questions, you'll get lots of help from the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/web2py).

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Stripes](http://www.stripesframework.org) on Google App Engine with success and pleasure. It's a simple yet really powerful MVC stack, very easy to learn and use, and with great documentation. I've been able to integrate it with Guide (for dependency injection) and Sitemesh (for page templating). If you're interested, the code for the application I developed is available at http://code.google.com/p/memwords/.

Answer (score 0):

Django is a best framework for projects without incredible high load, but GAE supported by a very old version.

Try to use [Pycharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/index.html) for editing GAE-applications. This is already usable IDE with active development

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/), it's a scalable, non-blocking web framework in python and it's simpler and easier to develop in than Django.